# How to access redux action while using connect() and NavigationContainer

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I'm working on a React Native project using Redux and `NavigationContainer`. I was using `useSelector()`, `useDispatch()` and everything was working fine.

To move forward, we have to use `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component);` instead of `useSelector()` and `useDispatch()`.

From what I understand while reading articles and docs, I can access both state values and actions from `props` in the same component that I passed into `connect()`.

In my case, the only parameter I can find is `({navigation, route})`, I can access the state like this: `route.params`. I tried to access the actions with `navigation` and `route`, which unfortunately didn't work.

connect.js

```
import {
  login,
  loggout,
} from './redux/actions';

export const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth,
});

const ActionCreators = Object.assign(
  {},
  login,
  loggout,
);

export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators(ActionCreators, dispatch),
});
```

App.js

```
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {PersistGate} from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import Main from './Main';
import configureStore from './store';

const App = () => {
  const {store, persistor} = configureStore();

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
        <Main />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Main.js

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps} from './connect';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Login from './screens/Login';

export const Main = () => {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Login"
        screenOptions={{
          headerTransparent: true,
          headerTintColor: colors.yellow,
        }}>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Login"
          component={Login}
          options={{headerShown: false}}
          initialParams={props}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);
```

Login.js

```
import {login} from '../redux/actions';
import {
  View,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';


const Login = ({navigation, route}) => {
  console.log('from Login');
  console.log(route.params); // state access
  // Here, how can I access the redux actions?
  console.log('-----------------');

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {route.params.auth.status === 'logged in' ? (
      <Text>Go To Profile</Text>
      ) : (
      <Text>Stay Here</Text>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};
```

The issue is, I can't access redux actions using props. How can I access them? Does `NavigationContainer` works with `connect()`? If I'm not using `NavigatorContainer` I can access an action like: `props.actionName()`, but with navigation is another situation.